# swipe to edit shows white background while deleting the row in xamarin IOS

Tags: xamarin.ios

I implemented swipe to delete feature for a tableview which displays custom cell. Whenever I delete the cell by swiping to left and clicking on delete button, for a brief moment it shows white background.

If I do a long swipe to delete I do not see any issues.

Any pointers on how to fix this.

Comment: Even with long swipe, I see white background for a while. Setting cell background to UIcolor.clear did not work.

Comment: Could you provide a GIF file or demonstrated image? It will be helpful.